# Creating python 2.7 daemon with pep-3143

Tags: python, daemon, python-daemon

Does anyone knows how to implement [python 2.7](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/)
as a Linux daemon? I'm looking for a working example with start/stop arguments.

Answer (score 7):

This following code is an example how to create a daemon using python on linux, if I not answered your question you should look this link http://ridingpython.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/turning-your-python-script-into-linux.html

main.py

```
import sys
from daemon import Daemon

class MyDaemon(Daemon):
    def run(self):
        print 'working'
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon = MyDaemon('/tmp/HMTd.pid')
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.restart()
        else:
            print "Unknown command"
            sys.exit(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(2)
```

class daemon.py

```
import sys, os, time, atexit
from signal import SIGTERM 

class Daemon:
    """
    A generic daemon class.
    
    Usage: subclass the Daemon class and override the run() method
    """
    def __init__(self, pidfile, stdin='/dev/stdin', stdout='/dev/stdout', stderr='/dev/stderr'):
        self.stdin = stdin
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.stderr = stderr
        self.pidfile = pidfile
    
    def daemonize(self):
        """
        do the UNIX double-fork magic, see Stevens' "Advanced 
        Programming in the UNIX Environment" for details (ISBN 0201563177)
        http://www.erlenstar.demon.co.uk/unix/faq_2.html#SEC16
        """
        try: 
            pid = os.fork() 
            if pid > 0:
                # exit first parent
                sys.exit(0) 
        except OSError, e: 
            sys.stderr.write("fork #1 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
            sys.exit(1)
    
        # decouple from parent environment
        os.chdir("/") 
        os.setsid() 
        os.umask(0) 
    
        # do second fork
        try: 
            pid = os.fork() 
            if pid > 0:
                # exit from second parent
                sys.exit(0) 
        except OSError, e: 
            sys.stderr.write("fork #2 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
            sys.exit(1) 
    
        # redirect standard file descriptors
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        si = file(self.stdin, 'r')
        so = file(self.stdout, 'a+')
        se = file(self.stderr, 'a+', 0)
        os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
        os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
    
        # write pidfile
        atexit.register(self.delpid)
        pid = str(os.getpid())
        file(self.pidfile,'w+').write("%s\n" % pid)
    
    def delpid(self):
        os.remove(self.pidfile)

    def start(self):
        """
        Start the daemon
        """
        # Check for a pidfile to see if the daemon already runs
        try:
            pf = file(self.pidfile,'r')
            pid = int(pf.read().strip())
            pf.close()
        except IOError:
            pid = None
    
        if pid:
            message = "pidfile %s already exist. Daemon already running?\n"
            sys.stderr.write(message % self.pidfile)
            sys.exit(1)
        
        # Start the daemon
        self.daemonize()
        self.run()

    def stop(self):
        """
        Stop the daemon
        """
        # Get the pid from the pidfile
        try:
            pf = file(self.pidfile,'r')
            pid = int(pf.read().strip())
            pf.close()
        except IOError:
            pid = None
    
        if not pid:
            message = "pidfile %s does not exist. Daemon not running?\n"
            sys.stderr.write(message % self.pidfile)
            return # not an error in a restart

        # Try killing the daemon process    
        try:
            while 1:
                os.kill(pid, SIGTERM)
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except OSError, err:
            err = str(err)
            if err.find("No such process") > 0:
                if os.path.exists(self.pidfile):
                    os.remove(self.pidfile)
            else:
                print str(err)
                sys.exit(1)

    def restart(self):
        """
        Restart the daemon
        """
        self.stop()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """
        You should override this method when you subclass Daemon. It will be called after the process has been
        daemonized by start() or restart().
        """
```

EDIT: I am not using that anymore. I nowadays prefer a `systemd` service:

```
[Unit]
Description=projectx python3 collector
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=ec2-user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env /bin/sh /home/ec2-user/projectx/run.sh
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -i projectx | awk '{print $2}') && killall chromedriver"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Do you think you would be able to turn this into a GitHub repository / PyPI package ? I would like to use it.

Comment: Umm, can you tell me where to place that file ?

Comment: @Programmer which distro are you using?

Comment: @Programmer .... the default path is /etc/systemd/system/your-service.service.

dont forget to do run enable command: 

`sudo systemctl enable your-service.service` and   
`sudo systemctl start your-service.service`